# Algorithm to find three elements which sum to zero in O(n log n) time complexity

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

Assume that the input array of n integers contains only integers between -5000n and 6000n.
We need to find an algorithm that determines whether array contains three elements whose
sum is zero, in O(n log n) time.

My Approach:

```
1. Sort in O(n log n) time.
2. Run a loop in O(n) time
3.     Fix two left and right pointers in the sorted array as the two endpoints
4.     find = SUM - (A[left] + A[right])
5.     Search for the third element (find) using binary search in O(log n)
6.     if found then return TRUE
7.     else 
8.
```

I'm stuck at step 8 that if the binary search algorithm returns false then how should adjust left and right pointers?

Also, will the whole algorithm work to find three elements that sum to zero, in every case since I'm not evaluating all possible combinations?

Hint - was given as use of polynomial FFT algorithm
[Ref1 FFT](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Erishig/courses/ref/l16.txt),
[Ref2 FFT](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Erishig/courses/ref/l17.txt)

Comment: Time complexity - O(n log n) has to be acheived

Comment: you can't make it nlogn

Comment: if you want O(n^2) soln I will share it with you

Comment: Yes, I know about the O(n log n) algorithm. The problem hint is to use a polynomial multiplication algorithm.  Here's a reference, Fast Fourier Transform algorithm application: https://cs.stanford.edu/~rishig/courses/ref/l16.txt

Comment: Ref: https://cs.stanford.edu/~rishig/courses/ref/l17.txt

Answer (score 1):

You are not on the path toward an O(N log N) algorithm.  Your algorithm will be either O(N<sup>2</sup>) or broken, depending on how you finish it.

The question is meant to be solved using FFT convolution, like this:

1. Allocate an array of size W, where W is a power of 2 and greater than 22001N.
2. Fill the array with zeros, and then set array[v+5000N]=1 for every value v in the input array.
3. Convolve the array with itself:  Compute the FFT, square each resulting value, and then compute the IFFT.
4. For each value v in the input, check to see if ifft[10000N-v] > 0.  If so, there are two numbers in the input that add up to -v.  Sort the input array and use a conventional two-pointer search to find those other two numbers.